# Krajee Bootstrap fileinput how can i change the uploadExtraData dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi Am using Krajee Bootstrap fileinput , i need to change the `uploadExtraData` dynamically on submitting the form. So i made it as a call back function. But it doesn't work for me. As i think `uploadExtraData` callback function work at on initialization only.

here is my code

```
$(".file-loading").fileinput({
     uploadUrl: document.location.origin + "/discussions/add",
     uploadAsync: false,
     uploadExtraData:getFormData(),
 });

function getFormData(){
    var project_id = $("#DiscussionProjectId").val();
    var discussion_title = $("#DiscussionDiscussionTitle").val();
    var comment = $('#discussionComment').attr('value');
    var data = {
        project_id:project_id,
        discussion_title:discussion_title,
        comment:comment
    };
    return data;
}
```

Am doing to save the input files and data on form submit only.

Comment: That's not how you define/pass callbacks, what you are doing there is invoking a function and passing the results. I'm sure there are a lot of duplicates as this is JavaScript 101, but I'm too lazy to search one that fits, so let me just say this: Remove the parentheses. `uploadExtraData: getFormData`

Answer (score 7):

I met the same problem with you,you can try this:

```
$(".file-loading").fileinput({
  uploadUrl: document.location.origin + "/discussions/add",
  uploadAsync: false,
  uploadExtraData:function(previewId, index) {
        var data = {
            project_id : $("#DiscussionProjectId").val(),
            discussion_title:$("#DiscussionDiscussionTitle").val(),
           comment:$('#discussionComment').attr('value')
        };
        return data;
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its also possible to destroy the control and recreate it again

```
self.jqueryObjects.fileInput.fileinput('destroy');

    self.jqueryObjects.fileInput.fileinput({
        showCaption: false,

        uploadUrl: self.urls.uploadDocument.replace(/<patient_id>/g, self.selectedPatient.id),

        allowedFileExtensions: ["txt"]
    });
```